# Two MQTT server pub/sub with python

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, mosquitto, paho

I've been trying to find answers or info about this question but without results yet. The idea is to publish the same topic into two different MQTT servers with python. I mean, something like this:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import datetime, time

mqttc = paho.Client()

host1 = "broker.hivemq.com" # the address of 1st mqtt broker
host2 = "192.168.1.200" # the address of 2nd mqtt broker
topic= "testingTopic"
port = 1883

def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
   print("on_connect() "+str(rc))

mqttc.on_connect = on_connect

print("Connecting to " + host)
mqttc.connect(host1, port, 60)
mqttc.connect(host2, port, 60)

while 1:
    # publish some data at a regular interval
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    mqttc.publish(topic, now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) #Publishing to MQTT1
    mqttc.publish(topic, now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) #Publishing to MQTT2
    time.sleep(1)
```

So, the question is about the while statment... how can I do to publish the same topic into MQTT1 and MQTT2? 
As you can see, I want to have to posibility to publish that payload in MQTT broker that is running in internet, but if I lose internet connection, then I can pub/sub to MQTT broker in my LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just connect the same client to 2 different brokers. You need 2 separate instances of the of the client that you connect to the separate brokers.

```
...
mqttc1 = paho.Client()
mqttc2 = paho.Client()
...
mqttc1.connect(host1, port, 60)
mqttc2.connect(host2, port, 60)
...
mqttc1.publish(topic, now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) #Publishing to MQTT1
mqttc2.publish(topic, now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) #Publishing to MQTT2
```

Comment: Sorry if in that moment I didn't say thank you. In that moment I was just a beginner without enough skills in stackoverflow and GitHub, where actually I have well documented all of this answers in order to avoid duplicate questions :)